# How to change font size without creating a new font

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to change the size of a font in .net winforms without having to create a new Font with the new size?

Comment: Why can't you just use the font property? Which control are you using? A label? A textbox?

Perhaps you're using a raster font that doesn't have bigger sizes available? Maybe you can switch to a TrueType or OpenType font.

Comment: I'm using a label that will reduce its font size when longer text are set to it to make sure they will fit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Font size is readonly for existing "Font" objects.

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this with an Extension method.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module FontExtensions

<Extension()> Public Function ToSize(ByVal OriginalFont As Font, ByVal NewSize As Single) As Font

        Dim NewFont As Font

        NewFont = New Font(OriginalFont.FontFamily, NewSize, OriginalFont.Style)

        Return NewFont

    End Function

End Module
```

and then call it like this...

```
SomeObject.Font = Font.ToSize(12)
```

It's still creating a new font behind the scenes, but your application code is not cluttered with the creation process.

Comment: Won't this be leaking Font-GDI objects ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the constructor method that allows you to use the base font and pass in the new size you desire.  This will save you some code from the other approaches.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...but turns out that only works with _style_ not size :(

Comment: Oops, you are correct. I remembered doing something like this but it was for creating a bold font from a non-bold font. Creating a different size font would require breaking out the necessary properties of the existing font.