# How to code buttons to increase/decrease text size everytime the button is clicked in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to code buttons to increase and decrease font sizes everytime the button is clicked (just like in word processing softwares). However, since I am a beginner in coding, I am not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```vb
Private Sub radFontBigger_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radFontBigger.Click

    Dim dblFontSize As Double = 9.75
    rtbCompose.font = New Font("Corbel", dblFontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
    dblFontSize += 1

End Sub
```

I tried to declare a variable and replace it as the font size, and would add 1 to the variable everytime the button is clicked.

Another attempt was to increase font size by 1 if fontSize is already at a certain size.

I debugged the form and nothing happened when the button is clicked. No text has increased in size.

Comment: Could you post the code you're referring to? You also need to define what framework you're using: WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net etc. Add some more details about this procedure: what Font are you trying to modify? The Font a specific Control/Element or the the Font all controls/elements in a Window/Form/Page? Click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58756744/edit) link to update your question.

Comment: For some context, see the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58743622/832052)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the existing font with the same font, but slightly larger.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font.FontFamily, TextBox1.Font.Size + 1, TextBox1.Font.Style)
End Sub
```

Modify `TextBox1.Font.Size + 1` to change how much the font size should grow or shrink. Check for zero / negative size (if shrinking). Possibly grow it by a percentage `TextBox1.Font.Size * 1.1!`, or shrink it similarly `TextBox1.Font.Size * 0.9!` to avoid negative sizes. Or iterate through a predefined list of sizes {8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, etc.}

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954539/832052) which does it the same way but in an extension method.

**Edit with your specific code implementation**

This version simply adds or subtracts 1 from the font size

```vb
Public Class Form1

    ' this should be declared outside the button click event handler, 
    ' otherwise it's being set back to 9.75 every time you click radFontBigger
    Private fontSize As Single = 9.75 ' made Single; Font constructor doesn't accept Double

    ' you should initialize the font size when your form opens
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

    Private Sub radFontBigger_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radFontBigger.Click
        fontSize += 1
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

    ' added this
    Private Sub radFontSmaller_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radFontSmaller.Click
        fontSize -= 1
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This version uses a dictionary to define a predefined list of font sizes

```vb
Public Class Form1

    ' dictionary holds index to font size
    Private ReadOnly fontSizes As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Single) _
        From {{0, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 10}, {3, 12}, {4, 14}, {5, 16}, {6, 18}, {7, 20}}

    ' current index, initialize according to dictionary (2 >> 10)
    Private fontSizeIndex As Integer = 2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSizes(fontSizeIndex), FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

    Private Sub radFontBigger_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radFontBigger.Click
        fontSizeIndex = Math.Min(fontSizes.Keys.Max, fontSizeIndex + 1)
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSizes(fontSizeIndex), FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

    Private Sub radFontSmaller_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radFontSmaller.Click
        fontSizeIndex = Math.Max(fontSizes.Keys.Min, fontSizeIndex - 1)
        rtbCompose.Font = New Font("Corbel", fontSizes(fontSizeIndex), FontStyle.Regular)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Could you show me the code to iterate through a predefined list of sizes?

Comment: I also could not make the code where we add "TextBox1.Font.Size + 1" to work. Could you also show me how, because nothing worked when I ran the program.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really a beginner, I hope you can help me. @djv

Comment: @Sam you didn't provide any code of your own, so I made a simple example which only requires a TextBox named `TextBox1` and Button named `Button1`. If you provide some code by editing your question, maybe I can make it work in your code.

Comment: I have edited the question to show you a code I have just tried. Sorry for the long response.